# Jquery migrate some code form .live() to .on()

Tags: jquery

How to migrate this code?

```
 $("#contact-form").find('textarea,input').jqBootstrapValidation({
            preventSubmit: true,
            submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
               
            },
            submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
 
                if (validate()) {
                    sendFormData();
                }
                else {
                    messageSendError("Warning! Please validate captcha before send new message.");
                }

                return false;

            },
            filter: function () {
                return $(this).is(":visible");
            },
        });
```

I try this one. No luck. What am I doing wrong?

```
 $(document).on('find', '#contact-form', 'textarea,input', function () {

            $(this).jqBootstrapValidation({
                preventSubmit: true,
                submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {

                },
                submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
                    event.preventDefault();    
                    if (validate()) {
                        // sendFormData();
                    }
                    else {
                        // messageSendError("Warning!.");
                    }

                    return false;

                },
                filter: function () {
                    return $(this).is(":visible");
                },
            });

        });
```

The 3th parameter which I pass is 'textarea,input'? Is this wrong? How to convert?

The live method was easy. This `.on()` is difficult and more complicated.

Some info

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use `live`, so it can't be converted to `on`.

Comment: Then just jQuery Migrate Some code with .on()?

Comment: You can't use `on`. `on` is for attaching events, your code needs to find an element and call a plugin method on it, it doesn't have anything to do with event delegation.

Comment: You have two selector statements in your [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/).. should be reduced to one: `$(document).on('find', '#contact-form textarea, #contact-form input', ...`. This might also work, depending on your DOM structure: `$('#contact-form').on('find', 'textarea,input', ...`